# Gauge JS remove margin

Tags: javascript, graph, highcharts, gauge, jsgauge

I am using gauge js in my code to show gauge graph on tv dashboards but the graph is showing extraspace in right and left side. Tried switching options but no use.
[image: graphs]

```
<div class="box-tile statitics m-w-324">
  <canvas style="height: 200px;width: 400px;" id="efficiencyGauge"></canvas>
    <span class="label">EFF. 
      <span class="value">
        <span id="efficiency" ="loading">...</span>
      </span>
    </span>
</div>  

var dhuGaugeOpts = {
    angle: -0.10,
    lineWidth: 0.2,
    radiusScale: 0.9,
    pointer: {
        length: 0.5,
        strokeWidth: 0.05,
        color: '#fff'
    },
    staticLabels: {
        font: "10px sans-serif",
        color: '#fff',
        labels: [2, 5],
        fractionDigits: 0
    },
    staticZones: [
        { strokeStyle: "#30B32D", min: 0, max: 2 },
        { strokeStyle: "#FFDD00", min: 2, max: 5 },
        { strokeStyle: "#F44336", min: 5, max: 10 },
    ],
    limitMax: false,
    limitMin: false,
    highDpiSupport: true,
    plotBackgroundColor: null,
    plotBackgroundImage: null,
    plotBorderWidth: 0,
    plotShadow: false,
    margin: [0, 0, 0, 0], // Adjust margins to remove whitespace
    spacing: [0, 0, 0, 0] // Adjust spacing to remove whitespace
};
dhuGauge = new Gauge(document.getElementById('dhuGauge')).setOptions(dhuGaugeOpts);
    dhuGauge.maxValue = 10;
    dhuGauge.setMinValue(0);
```

I tried different properties but no use. I am using library gauge.js
Is there any specific property for this. cause of using this on tv I can't change the library since all tv browser doesn't support new libraries

Comment: You've mentioned Highcharts in the tags, but your code doesn't seem to reference the Highcharts library. Please clarify your technology stack and provide clearer config to receive the most relevant assistance.

Comment: The extra space to the left and right is the result of your choice of options and of the fact that the gauge is always round. Most importantly, the `angle: -0.1` extends the gauge considerably more than a half circle (so its height has to be more than the half the width). If you set `angle: 0` you'd have a half circle and with a `radiusScale: 1.1` you'd almost fill a 400px x 200px canvas (still some space caused by the end of the pointer). But you could always change the size of
the canvas's css (with your original options you can go `height: 200px; width: 280px`) to eliminate empty space.